# Integration of drake to OpenSUSE - build error with spdlog and fmt Part 2

Tags: c++, cmake, drake, fmt, spdlog

I am trying to integrate drake to OpenSUSE in this [repository](https://github.com/hedaniel7/Drake-OpenSUSE-Integration/tree/main)

This question is most probably related to the problem state [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78122252/integration-of-drake-to-opensuse-build-error-with-spdlog-and-fmt).
I am opening a different question on this topic, because this situation is advanced to a new state and can be seen as the follow-up to the previous question.

I have tried your advice of executing it with the official binaries of spdlog and fmt like you suggested in your previous answer

> if SUSE already has any build of spdlog or fmt, it would be ideal to
> use those instead of building from source.

I tried to do this with the following Dockerfile

```
# Use OpenSUSE Leap 15.4 as base
FROM opensuse/leap:15.4

# Install vim, sudo, and other necessary tools and libraries for drake
RUN zypper --non-interactive update && \
    zypper --non-interactive install -y vim sudo git cmake make java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel \
    glib2-devel lapack-devel libX11-devel ocl-icd-devel opencl-headers patch patchelf \
    pkg-config python3-devel python3-pygame zlib-devel pkg-config eigen3-devel \
    libmumps5 mumps-devel gcc-fortran nasm wget\  
    spdlog-devel  # spdlog-devel install spdlog-devel and fmt-devel
    # llvm-clang llvm-clang-devel not installed as there are too old

# Add the repository for GCC 10
RUN zypper addrepo -f http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/openSUSE_Leap_15.4/ devel_gcc && \
    zypper --non-interactive --gpg-auto-import-keys refresh && \
    zypper --non-interactive install -y gcc10 gcc10-c++

# Set GCC 10 as the default compiler
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 100 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 30 && \
    update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 30 && \
    update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++

# Install Bazelisk
RUN curl -L https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.7.5/bazelisk-linux-amd64 > /usr/local/bin/bazelisk && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/bazelisk && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/bazelisk /usr/local/bin/bazel

# Download and place jchart2d-3.3.2.jar in /usr/share/java/jchart2d.jar
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jchart2d/jchart2d/3.3.2/jchart2d-3.3.2.jar -O /usr/share/java/jchart2d.jar

# Create .pc files for LAPACK and BLAS
RUN echo -e "prefix=/usr\nexec_prefix=\${prefix}\nlibdir=\${exec_prefix}/lib64\nincludedir=\${prefix}/include\n\nName: LAPACK\nDescription: Linear Algebra Package\nVersion: 3.9.0\nLibs: -L\${libdir} -llapack\nCflags: -I\${includedir}" > /usr/share/pkgconfig/lapack.pc && \
    echo -e "prefix=/usr\nexec_prefix=\${prefix}\nlibdir=\${exec_prefix}/lib64\nincludedir=\${prefix}/include\n\nName: BLAS\nDescription: Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms\nVersion: 3.9.0\nLibs: -L\${libdir} -lblas\nCflags: -I\${includedir}" > /usr/share/pkgconfig/blas.pc

# Set up the environment for user 'dan'
RUN groupadd -r dan && \
    useradd -m -s /bin/bash -r -g dan dan && \
    mkdir -p /home/dan/drake && \
    chown -R dan:dan /home/dan/drake && \
    echo "dan ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER dan
ENV HOME /home/dan
WORKDIR $HOME

# Install dependencies for pyenv and Python build
RUN sudo zypper --non-interactive install -y git gcc make zlib-devel libbz2-devel libopenssl-devel readline-devel \
    sqlite3-devel tar gzip openmpi-devel python3-clang15 clang15-devel

# Install pyenv and Python 3.10
RUN git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git $HOME/.pyenv && \
    echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"\nfi' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc && pyenv install 3.10.0 && pyenv global 3.10.0"

# Ensure the selected Python version 3.10 is used and install PyYAML
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc && pyenv rehash && pip install PyYAML"

# Set environment variables for GCC to ensure Bazel uses the correct version
ENV CC=/usr/bin/gcc-10
ENV CXX=/usr/bin/g++-10
ENV PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
ENV PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Installing `spdlog-devel` with zypper you automatically get `spdlog-devel` version 1.9.2-bp154.1.41 + `fmt-devel` version 8.0.1-150400.1.8 installed together.

They are located here

```
dan@169dafd51f9a:~/drake/cmake> find /usr -name fmt*
/usr/bin/fmt
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/fmt.pc
/usr/lib64/cmake/fmt
/usr/lib64/cmake/fmt/fmt-config-version.cmake
/usr/lib64/cmake/fmt/fmt-targets.cmake
/usr/lib64/cmake/fmt/fmt-targets-relwithdebinfo.cmake
/usr/lib64/cmake/fmt/fmt-config.cmake
/usr/share/doc/packages/fmt-devel
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/fmtmsg.ph
/usr/include/spdlog/details/fmt_helper.h
/usr/include/spdlog/fmt
/usr/include/spdlog/fmt/fmt.h
/usr/include/fmtmsg.h
/usr/include/fmt
dan@169dafd51f9a:~/drake/cmake> find /usr -name spdlog*
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/spdlog.pc
/usr/lib64/cmake/spdlog
/usr/lib64/cmake/spdlog/spdlogConfigVersion.cmake
/usr/lib64/cmake/spdlog/spdlogConfig.cmake
/usr/lib64/cmake/spdlog/spdlogConfigTargets.cmake
/usr/lib64/cmake/spdlog/spdlogConfigTargets-release.cmake
/usr/share/doc/packages/spdlog-devel
/usr/share/licenses/spdlog-devel
/usr/include/spdlog
/usr/include/spdlog/spdlog-inl.h
/usr/include/spdlog/spdlog.h
```

That's the reason I modify the following cmake command to

`cmake .. -DWITH_USER_FMT:BOOLEAN=ON -DWITH_USER_SPDLOG:BOOLEAN=ON -Dfmt_DIR="/usr/lib64/cmake/fmt" -Dspdlog_DIR="/usr/lib64/cmake/spdlog"`

I get the following error with it:

```
dan@169dafd51f9a:~/drake/cmake> cmake .. -DWITH_USER_FMT:BOOLEAN=ON -DWITH_USER_SPDLOG:BOOLEAN=ON -Dfmt_DIR="/usr/lib64/cmake/fmt" -Dspdlog_DIR="/usr/lib64/cmake/spdlog" 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.5.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-10 - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-10 - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:60 (message):
  Could NOT find the lsb_release executable


-- Found Bazel: /usr/local/bin/bazel (Required is at least version "5.1") 
-- Found Python: /home/dan/.pyenv/shims/python3.10 (found suitable exact version "3.10.0") found components: Development Interpreter Development.Module Development.Embed 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.35.3") 
fatal: not a git repository: /home/dan/drake/../.git/modules/drake
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Reading 'startup' options from /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd/.bazelrc: --output_base=/home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=0 --terminal_columns=80
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/tools/bazel.rc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --enable_bzlmod=false
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --announce_rc=no --repo_env=CC=/usr/bin/gcc-10 --repo_env=CXX=/usr/bin/g++-10
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/tools/bazel.rc:
  Inherited 'build' options: -c opt --strip=never --strict_system_includes --cxxopt=-std=c++20 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++20 --test_output=errors --test_summary=terse --test_tag_filters=-gurobi,-mosek,-snopt --test_env=DISPLAY --test_env=GRB_LICENSE_FILE --test_env=MOSEKLM_LICENSE_FILE --test_env=LCM_DEFAULT_URL=memq:// --test_env=MPLBACKEND=Template
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/tools/ubuntu.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --force_pic --fission=dbg --features=per_object_debug_info --action_env=PATH=/usr/bin:/bin --action_env=PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1 --test_env=PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --symlink_prefix=/ --color=yes --subcommands=no --package_path=%workspace%:/home/dan/drake --notrim_test_configuration --action_env=CCACHE_DISABLE=1 --config=Release
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:Release in file /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd/.bazelrc: --compilation_mode=opt
bazel-bin: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin
bazel-genfiles: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin
bazel-testlogs: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/testlogs
character-encoding: file.encoding = ISO-8859-1, defaultCharset = ISO-8859-1
command_log: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/command.log
committed-heap-size: 520MB
execution_root: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake
gc-count: 4
gc-time: 32ms
install_base: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dan/install/117cee491f5c7d83be6e3c6d6b5b8ca4
java-home: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dan/install/117cee491f5c7d83be6e3c6d6b5b8ca4/embedded_tools/jdk
java-runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-LTS) by Azul Systems, Inc.
java-vm: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode) by Azul Systems, Inc.
max-heap-size: 8304MB
output_base: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3
output_path: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake/bazel-out
package_path: %workspace%:/home/dan/drake
release: release 6.4.0
repository_cache: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dan/cache/repos/v1
server_log: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/java.log.169dafd51f9a.dan.log.java.20240314-153358.25326
server_pid: 25326
used-heap-size: 83MB
workspace: /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dan/drake/cmake
dan@169dafd51f9a:~/drake/cmake> make install
INFO: Analyzed target //:install (324 packages loaded, 26689 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/dan/drake/common/symbolic/expression/BUILD.bazel:19:17: Compiling common/symbolic/expression/formula_cell.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc-10 failed: error executing command (from target //common/symbolic/expression:_everything_compiled_cc_impl) /usr/bin/gcc-10 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 88 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
In file included from bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/common/_virtual_includes/fmt/drake/common/fmt.h:6,
                 from bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/common/_virtual_includes/copyable_unique_ptr/drake/common/copyable_unique_ptr.h:18,
                 from bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/common/_virtual_includes/_random_headers_cc_impl/drake/common/random.h:8,
                 from bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/common/symbolic/expression/_virtual_includes/_everything_compiled_cc_impl/drake/common/symbolic/expression/formula_cell.h:17,
                 from common/symbolic/expression/formula_cell.cc:2:
external/fmt/include/fmt/format.h: In instantiation of 'std::string fmt::v8::to_string(const T&) [with T = drake::symbolic::Expression; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Tp>::value), int>::type <anonymous> = 0; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':
bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/common/_virtual_includes/fmt/drake/common/fmt_eigen.h:80:38:   required from 'fmt::v8::formatter<drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Derived> >::format<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >::<lambda(const auto:19&)> [with auto:19 = drake::symbolic::Expression; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
external/eigen/include/_usr_include_eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h:583:22:   required from 'Eigen::internal::unary_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<UnaryOp, ArgType>, Eigen::internal::IndexBased>::CoeffReturnType Eigen::internal::unary_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<UnaryOp, ArgType>, Eigen::internal::IndexBased>::coeff(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) const [with UnaryOp = fmt::v8::formatter<drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Derived> >::format<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >::<lambda(const auto:19&)>; ArgType = const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >; typename Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<UnaryOp, ArgType>::Scalar = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Eigen::internal::unary_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<UnaryOp, ArgType>, Eigen::internal::IndexBased>::CoeffReturnType = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Eigen::Index = long int]'
external/eigen/include/_usr_include_eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:654:63:   required from 'void Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<DstEvaluatorTypeT, SrcEvaluatorTypeT, Functor, Version>::assignCoeff(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with DstEvaluatorTypeT = Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >; SrcEvaluatorTypeT = Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<fmt::v8::formatter<drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Derived> >::format<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >::<lambda(const auto:19&)>, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > > >; Functor = Eigen::internal::assign_op<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; int Version = 0; Eigen::Index = long int]'
external/eigen/include/_usr_include_eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:668:16:   required from 'void Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<DstEvaluatorTypeT, SrcEvaluatorTypeT, Functor, Version>::assignCoeffByOuterInner(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with DstEvaluatorTypeT = Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >; SrcEvaluatorTypeT = Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<fmt::v8::formatter<drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Derived> >::format<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >::<lambda(const auto:19&)>, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > > >; Functor = Eigen::internal::assign_op<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; int Version = 0; Eigen::Index = long int]'
external/eigen/include/_usr_include_eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:347:39:   required from 'static void Eigen::internal::dense_assignment_loop<Kernel, 0, 0>::run(Kernel&) [with Kernel = Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<fmt::v8::formatter<drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Derived> >::format<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >::<lambda(const auto:19&)>, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > > >, Eigen::internal::assign_op<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, 0>]'
external/eigen/include/_usr_include_eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:785:37:   [ skipping 7 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
external/fmt/include/fmt/core.h:1172:19:   required from 'constexpr fmt::v8::detail::value<Context>::value(const T&) [with T = drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > >; Context = fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char>]'
external/fmt/include/fmt/core.h:1571:14:   required from 'constexpr fmt::v8::detail::value<Context> fmt::v8::detail::make_arg(const T&) [with bool IS_PACKED = true; Context = fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char>; fmt::v8::detail::type <anonymous> = fmt::v8::detail::type::custom_type; T = drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> > >; typename std::enable_if<IS_PACKED, int>::type <anonymous> = 0]'
external/fmt/include/fmt/core.h:1694:64:   required from 'constexpr fmt::v8::format_arg_store<Context, Args>::format_arg_store(const Args& ...) [with Context = fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char>; Args = {drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<-1> > >}]'
external/fmt/include/fmt/core.h:1710:18:   required from 'constexpr fmt::v8::format_arg_store<Context, Args ...> fmt::v8::make_format_args(const Args& ...) [with Context = fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char>; Args = {drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<-1> > >}]'
external/fmt/include/fmt/core.h:2886:44:   required from 'std::string fmt::v8::format(fmt::v8::format_string<T ...>, T&& ...) [with T = {drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<-1> > >}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; fmt::v8::format_string<T ...> = fmt::v8::basic_format_string<char, drake::internal::fmt_eigen_ref<Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<drake::symbolic::Expression, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<-1> > > >]'
common/symbolic/expression/formula_cell.cc:584:21:   required from here
external/fmt/include/fmt/format.h:2602:22: error: call of overloaded 'write<char>(std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, const drake::symbolic::Expression&)' is ambiguous
 2602 |   detail::write<char>(std::back_inserter(result), value);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
external/fmt/include/fmt/format.h:1819:6: note: candidate: 'OutputIt fmt::v8::detail::write(OutputIt, T) [with Char = char; OutputIt = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; T = drake::symbolic::Expression; typename std::enable_if<std::integral_constant<bool, (std::numeric_limits<_UIntType>::is_iec559 && (sizeof (T) <= sizeof (double)))>::value, int>::type <anonymous> = 0]'
 1819 | auto write(OutputIt out, T value) -> OutputIt {
      |      ^~~~~
external/fmt/include/fmt/format.h:1944:20: note: candidate: 'constexpr typename std::enable_if<(fmt::v8::detail::type_constant<decltype (fmt::v8::detail::arg_mapper<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<OutputIt, Char> >().map(declval<const T&>())), typename fmt::v8::basic_format_context<OutputIt, Char>::char_type>::value == fmt::v8::detail::type::custom_type), OutputIt>::type fmt::v8::detail::write(OutputIt, const T&) [with Char = char; OutputIt = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; T = drake::symbolic::Expression; typename std::enable_if<(fmt::v8::detail::type_constant<decltype (fmt::v8::detail::arg_mapper<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<OutputIt, Char> >().map(declval<const T&>())), typename fmt::v8::basic_format_context<OutputIt, Char>::char_type>::value == fmt::v8::detail::type::custom_type), OutputIt>::type = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
 1944 | FMT_CONSTEXPR auto write(OutputIt out, const T& value) ->
      |                    ^~~~~
Target //:install failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 12.924s, Critical Path: 5.35s
INFO: 12 processes: 9 internal, 3 processwrapper-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/build.make:70: CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:839: CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowest fmt version that Drake tests in its CI is 8.1.1.

It looks like fmt version 8.0.1 is missing this bug fix:
https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/commit/ee0659f8b6dafa84f90576ae85adc77c20517286 that was released in 8.1.0.

From reading the fmt source code, it looks like a work-around might be to make the Expression class larger than sizeof(double), e.g., with this patch:

```
--- a/common/symbolic/expression/boxed_cell.h
+++ b/common/symbolic/expression/boxed_cell.h
@@ -360,6 +360,8 @@ class BoxedCell {
   // Leaving it non-redundantly initialized here is slightly faster.
   double value_;
 #endif
+
+  int fmt_v801_padding_;
 };
 
 }  // namespace internal
```